# How many ways are there to split a dozen people into $3$ teams , where one team has $2$ people and the other two teams have $5$ people each?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem $:$

> How many ways are there to split a dozen people into $3$ teams , where one team has $2$ people and the other two teams have $5$ people each?

My try, Pick $2$ guys  from $12$ guys which gives  $12 \choose 2$ , now we have  $10$ people left from which two  $5$ person teams are to be made..it gives  $10 \choose 5$ choices. .Thus we have ${12 \choose 2} \times {10 \choose 5}$ choices to make such three teams. Am I right?

Comment: THese are 0 ways, because $12\not = 3 + 5 + 5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean one team of two people and two teams of five people. Once we have picked the two people who form a first team, we can select five out of ten people to form the second group. However, since we counted each combination twice (putting five people in the second results in the same division as putting them in the third group), we must divide by two. As such, the number of possible combinations equals:

$$\frac{{12 \choose 2} {10 \choose 5}}{2} = \frac{66 \cdot 252}{2} = 8316$$

Comment: Sorry,  I didn't understand how we counted each combination twice. Please explain me more rigorously.

Comment: @Subhajit Saha see my hint above and try to figure out the double counting argument.

Comment: Observe that $(a\ b) (c\ d\ e\ f\ g) (h\ i\ j\ k\ l) = (a\ b) (h\ i\  j\ k\ l) (c\ d\ e\ f\ g).$

Comment: The same way when you are trying to figure out how many elements are there in  $S_4$ of the form $(a\ b) (c\ d)$? What is the answer you will end up with? Is it ${4 \choose 2} \times {2 \choose 2}$ or $\frac {{4 \choose 2} \times {2 \choose 2}} {2}$?

Comment: If I stuck with my argument then I'm choosing  both (c d e f g ) and (h i j k l)...as the first group of five people. ..but both of them are same if you consider their respective second group of five people,  here's the problem, and so you are dividing by 2. I think you are saying this.

Comment: @SubhajitSaha Indeed, choosing $(c d e f g)$ in the first step results in the same division of groups as choosing $(h i j k l)$. Therefore, we must divide by two.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I guess you have understand that I'm a beginner in probability, I have just started to read Introduction to probability by Blitzstein and Hwang. But the problem is there are no answer of exercise problems except for some selective problems. But I'm loving to read it. Can you suggest me to solve another book that contain exercise answers but can be solved just by reading the book that I like?

Comment: You may read "Elementary probability theory with stochastic processes" written by Kai Lai Chung. It is taught at RKMVERI,Belur Math.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ How many elements are there of the form $(a\ b) (c\ d\ e\ f\ g) (i\ j\ k\ l\ m)$ in $S_{12}$?

Comment: Bujhte perecho @Subhajit Saha?